# How can I add a custom context menu item on a text selection in the Terminal?

Tags: shortcut-menu

When I am using the Terminal, I can select a URL in the text and open a context menu that lets me "Open URL". What I would like to do is customize the behavior of this "Open URL" action or add another alternative action that lets me run a custom bash script that takes the URL as an argument. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK no, but you can make an new `Service` with the `Automator.app`.

And the new service will appear in the "Services" submenu in the context menu.

Assuming than you're familiar with scripting and Automator - if not, enter more details what you want achieve with the URL... (for an example can check: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/63362/6838)