# How do I create an Automator-based "Replace Text" Service that works with sandboxing?

Tags: applescript, automator, services, sandbox

I want to create a Service using Automator on macOS 10.12.6.

I selected:

> Service receives selected **rich text** in **any application**
>   Input is **entire selection** ☑️ Output replaces selected text

I then plan to transform the text using AppleScript. Easy enough, right? But I've created several Services using this approach, and when I select them in TextEdit, the services all fail. I see the spinner icon momentarily, and I'm not shown an error dialog.

In Console.app, I see this error:

```
sandboxd
Subsystem: com.apple.sandbox.reporting Category: violation
SandboxViolation: TextEdit(11092) deny file-read-data /Users/somebody/Library/Services/Demo.workflow
Violation: deny file-read-data /Users/somebody/Library/Services/Demo.workflow
```

How do I get my Service to comply with Sandbox restrictions?

Comment: I can duplicate that error if I set it to receive rich text. It goes away if you set it to receive text. Do you have a specific reason you need rich text? As far as I know, the Run AppleScript parameter doesn't understand rich text.

Comment: @Hurston That's true. If I select "text", I do not encounter the same sandbox issue. Unfortunately, the service then outputs raw RTF markup into my rich-text document if I select this option. (I want to change the font, [similar to this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63335/in-keynote-is-there-any-way-to-assign-shortcut-keys-to-select-specific-fonts/63362#63362).)